# Why does the PACF graduallly decline for MA time series model?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, moving-average

If we have some time series data that follows ARMA(p=0,q=n), why does the PACF gradually decline?

Comment: Have you tried obtaining an explicit PACF expression for an MA process? That could be a good start.